# How do I obtain the order of insertion in a boost multi index container?

Tags: boost, boost-multi-index

Disclaimer: I am new to multi_index_container

I am creating a boost multi_index_container with three comparators. I would like an additional criteria  that gives me the order of insertion into the container. Is this possible?

Comment: Voting to close this one. The linked issue suggests using a random access iterator.

Comment: Nah. Instead, it _explains_ (not suggests) to use a `random_access` index (not iterator).